# Loop using jLabels in swing

Tags: java, swing, loops, jlabel

how can a make a loop using this labels instead of creating 40 lines of code "repeating" them

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/cards/"+cards.get(1)+".png"))); 
jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/cards/"+cards.get(1)+".png"))); 
jLabel3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/cards/"+cards.get(2)+".png"))); 
jLabel4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/cards/"+cards.get(3)+".png")));
```

Comment: for real?   i know i have to make a for loop. the question is how can i change the jLabel name in the loop i needed something like jLabel(i), and that isn't possible

Comment: Things like array or ArrayList can contain JLabel.

Comment: There's not enough context for an improvement. How do you create jLabel1 through jLabel40? There's the root of the evil you are feeling.

Comment: You don't edit the answer in order to say thanks @Rodrigo, you just click accept on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write a loop.  So set `i` to 0 (`int i=0`), while it is less than 40 (`i<40`), continue to loop, every loop add 1 to `i` (`i++`)

```
 for (int i=0; i<40; i++)
 {
 }
```

Then you insert the code to be looped, using the changing `i` to index whatever it is you want to index

```
 for (int i=0; i<40; i++)
 {
    //do something with i - which is increased by one every loop through
 }
```

In your case, you will need to create a bunch of labels though as

```
 JLabel[] jLabels = new JLabel[40];
```

Then you can index each label inside your loop

```
//Notice there are two uses of the i variable here
String imageLocation = "/cards/" + cards.get(i) + ".png";
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(imageLocation));
jLabels[i].setIcon(icon);
```

But you will need to have a simple loop (before the one above ... or within it) in order to fill the `jLabels` array with `new JLabel()` objects.  I've given you all the tools you need to do that.

Comment: it's only replace image

Comment: This would just put the last image on the first label.

Answer (score 0):

The way that i like to do it, is to create a Vector object that holds JLabels, like below.

```
private Vector<JLabel> vecLabels = new Vector<JLabel>();
```

After that you can go on and create a method called createLabel() that take in a name, text, width, height and other options you wish to set. For example you may want to set the location of the label or even add a actionListener to it. Below is what i like to take in and set.

```
public void createLabel(String text, String name, Dimension size, Point location) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text); // Creates the JLabel
        label.setName(name); // Sets the name
        label.setSize(size); // Sets the size
        label.setLocation(location); // Sets the location
        vecLabel.add(label); // Adds the JLabel to the vecLabels. ()
        add(label); // Adds the label to the JFrame.
}
```

And to call the method.

```
createLabel("Name:", "lblName", new Dimension(100, 25), new Point(xPos, yPos));
```

If you need to get the label you will need to add a getter for the vector and to get the label put.

```
 public JLabel getLabel(int index) {
        return vecLabel.get(index);
    }
    private JLabel lblLabel = getLabel(Index);
```

Hope this helps.